# Some questions about using the useEffect hook

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new in react-native and the hooks. In my react-native project, I have one screen needs to query `data` from backend, then, there are some code using the backend returned `data` should only be run once when the screen mounted. This is what I did (I am using [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) for data fetching from backend):

```js
const MyScreen = ()=> {
   // fetch data from backend or cache, just think this code gets data from backend if you don't know react-query
   const {status, data, error} = useQuery(['get-my-data'], httpClient.fetchData);

   // these code only need to run once when screen mounted, that's why I use useEffect hook.
   useEffect(() => {
      // check data
      console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
      
      // a function to process data
      const processedData = processeData(data);
      
      return () => {
        console.log('Screen did unmount');
      };
   }, []);

   return (<View>
            {/* I need to show processed data here, but the processedData is scoped in useEffect hook & I need to have the process data function in useEffect since only need it to be run once */}
           </View>)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Does react native guarantee the order that the code above `useEffect` is invoked always first after that run the `useEffect` code?
2. As you can see the `processedData` is returned inside useEffect, how can I pass that return to the layout code to render the processed data?

Comment: 1 - I think that's the idea, that everything in the render block happens first, then the effects happen afterwards, but you would need to add `data` to your array otherwise when the data returns, your effect won't rerun because it has no dependencies. 2 useState

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean `in the render block` exactly? Do you mean the `return` part or from the beginning of `MyScreen`?

Comment: sorry I mean the entire function. (a functional component is the same as the "render" function from class based components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** `useEffect` is run after the component has fully rendered and does not block the browser's painting. Consider this example:

```js
export default function App() {
  console.log("I am code from the app")
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am the effect")
  })
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am the layout effect")
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("I am inside the jsx")}
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Will output:

```
I am code from the app
I am inside the jsx
I am the layout effect
I am the effect
```

So the `useEffect` callback will happen as the last thing, after everything else has been done.

**Second Question:** You can only pass that by using `useState` and setting the state inside your effect:

```js
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Your other code
    const processedData = processeData(data);
    setData(processedData)
  }, [setData])
```